# Are gentiles prohibited from striking another gentile?

Tags: gentiles, halacha-theory, noachide-laws, violence

Is a gentile forbidden from striking another gentile?

For example: If a gentile finds himself faced with an individual (who is likewise a gentile) who repeatedly intimidates, insults and/or otherwise harasses them/causes them chronic problems, and, "in the heat of the moment" strikes (i.e. punches) that person, is he committing a sin?

I did not see a mention of this in the 7 Noahide laws and would like clarification on this matter. I am interested specifically in the Orthodox interpretation.

Comment: While I think this is a good question, I'm wondering if this question belong son this site as it doesn't focus on Judaism. Other opinions?

Comment: @DanF since the Noachide laws are a Jewish concept, I think asking *what Judaism says* about them is in scope.  It's not our first question of this type.

Comment: @DanF while I am not halachically a Jew because my mother was not Jewish (therefore making me a gentile), my father was an (ethnic) Jew and my ancestors from his side of the family worshipped the God of Israel. I feel that their God is my God and still feel obligated to observe the religious laws prescribed in Judaism for people like me. Therefore I ask this question here because it is important to me and very much focused on Judaism, despite my status as a gentile (Judaism includes laws for gentiles as well - the Noahide laws)

Comment: Maimonedes is quite strict that one is never allowed to possess anger. I sense that his rules apply to humanity, not just Jews. Your stating punching "in the heat of the moment" would be violating this principal. Maimonedes equates possessing anger with idolatry. And, we know that one of the Noahide laws prohibits idolatry.

Comment: I'm not sure I can properly answer this question, but I can direct others: See Sanhedrin נח:, especially Rishonim and Acharonim, as well as Rambam מלכים 10:6 and Mefarshim there and its very possible that we could be dealing with a Chiyuv Misah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Ramban in Vayshlach (34:13)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22260&st=&pgnum=271) holds that the noachides are prohibited from (all derivations of) injuring others because of their laws of dinim.

Therefore, in your example, that person could fulfill a mitzvah (by bringing the one who harasses him/her to a court).